# get date of 3rd friday in the month with SQL without using level function

Tags: sql, plsql

get date of 3rd Friday in the month with SQL (without using level function), also Business days in a month & 3rd Friday for all months, thank you

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Comment: for all the months? single month? please mention more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also, please edit your expectations alongside that process. **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server version here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120488/determine-3rd-friday-of-each-month

Comment: Just find how to replace T-SQL functions with PLSQL equivalents like `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY')`

Comment: Why don't you want to use connect by (with level)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that will get you the 3rd Friday in the month for all months in 2016. I'm not sure why you want to avoid using connect by and level, though.

```
with months as (select to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/04/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/08/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/09/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/11/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual union all
                select to_date('01/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_of_month from dual)
select start_of_month,
       next_day(start_of_month - 1, 'FRIDAY') + 14 third_friday_in_month
from   months;
```

As for your requirement to get the number of business days in a month, it depends on what you mean by "business days". Do you mean weekdays? Or weekdays minus public holidays? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('JAN-2016','MON-YYYY')+13, 'FRIDAY') THIRD_FRIDAY FROM dual;
```

13 : Is to use 3rd week (addition of 13 days)

Comment: welcome :) If it solved your purpose then please accept the answer.